# Optimizer: replace const reference with const object

Tags: c++, optimization

Chandler Carruth in his [talk](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qkzaZumt_uk) on compiler optimization said that compilers are terrible at optimizing functions with parameters passed by reference. I can understand that it is difficult when parameter is a non-const reference, since the compiler has to deal with memory, or when type of the parameter is complex (some weird structure or class). But if the parameter is const reference and a builtin type are there really any problems? Can optimizer replace `const float&` with `const float`? It can be even more helpful when use of SSE instructions is enabled since compiler will be able properly align data for them.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> Can optimizer replace `const float&` with `const float`?

No, they cannot do that, because it may change the semantic of the program. A `const` reference is still a reference. It cannot be replaced by value. Consider this example:

```
void foo(const float& x, float a[]) {
    cout << x << endl;
    a[0] += 10.5;
    cout << x << endl;
}

int main() {
    float a[1] = { 3.25 };
    foo(a[0], a);
    return 0;
}
```

This prints

```
3.25
13.75
```

[Demo 1](http://ideone.com/JdyxGF)

If you change `const float&` with `const float`, the result would be

```
3.25
3.25
```

[Demo 2](http://ideone.com/dtpRSv)

The issue here is that `a[0]` is the same as `x`, but the connection is established by the caller, which is outside of optimizer's control.

Comment: Didn't thought about this case. Also, this kind of code might be a nightmare for those who will have to debug it :)

Comment: What if the function is inlined?

Comment: @NeilKirk: Then the as-if-rule applies, and I expect *all* references to be eliminated. As well as the array, and the addition. All output might even be flattened to a single byte-sequence...

Comment: Would it make sense to define something like `template<typename T>
using fastest_immutable = std::conditional_t<(sizeof(T) <= sizeof(void*)), T, const T&>;` to define generic functions that do not mutate their arguments and avoid unnecessary expensive copies? [godbolt example](https://goo.gl/lQAVbp)

Comment: @VittorioRomeo I wouldn't do it universally, primarily for readability of code, but also to help optimizer a little. Writing template code would be one notable exception, though.

Comment: After reading a bit about LLVM analysis passes I found out that there are some cases when reference could be promoted to the value itself. See http://llvm.org/docs/Passes.html#id46

Answer (score 4):

I listened to (whatched) that talk on Youtube a while back.

The optimiser can not replace references if it doesn't know what the function actually does. E.g.

func.c:

```
 float func(const float& f)
 {
    return f * 2;
 }
```

main.c:

```
 float complicated()
 {
     float f = 3.0;
     float f2 = func(f);
     f2 += 42 + f;
     return f2 / 17.0;
 }

 int main()
 {
    std::cout << complicated() << std::endl;
 }
```

So even tho' `f` in complicated isn't being modified in `func`, the compiler doesn't KNOW this. So it has to pass `f` as a reference, and `func`.

If the function is inlineable (because it's in the same source and short enough), then it can indeed inline the function and remove the reference use. But if the source of the function is in a different function, you can't know what that function does.

If the source is not available, the compiler has to pass by reference, because it's the contract of the function - the arguments are passed differently for one thing, but even if that wasn't the case [as dasblinkenlight shows in that answer] the meaning of the code can change if the argument is a reference or not.

Answer (score 3):

Yet another reason why this substitution cannot be made is that the function can actually const cast away the constness, and then mutate the variable, which would be reflected in the calling scope. This is only UB if the variable passed in is const. That is:

```
void f(const int & x) {
  const_cast<int &>(x) = 0;
}

int x = 1;
f(x);
```

Is legal and does what you'd expect. Of course, this code is hideous etc, but still legal. Change the const reference to a by-value pass and you would change the program, making the compiler non-conformant. Because of const_cast and how broadly it can be used, compilers don't really make any use of const (except to some degree in local variables); Chandler mentions this as well in one of his talks.

Answer (score 2):

> But if the parameter is const reference and a builtin type are there
>   really any problems?

It's not really for being to a "complex" or to a built-in type that references are "hard" to optimize. The problem is *aliasing*, which is a much worse beast to deal with that affects pointers and references due to their intrinsic nature.

> Can optimizer replace const float& with const float?

@dasblinkenlight makes a very good example were that optimization would not be possible as it affects the visible behavior of the code, which optimizers cannot alter. The realistic regression is that usually `sizeof (float&) > sizeof(float)`, so you're technically consuming more bytes for that parameter; while true, it's effectively irrelevant, especially if passed in a register.

For those limited memory accesses, in both count and side-effect possibilities, aliasing is unlikely to be a problem, or still not worth employing techniques to try to optimize it.